# How to do authentication using active directory group in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to do validation of users using "active directory" group. For that I am using this

```
private void LoadSourceAccessContextInfo()
{
    if (Context.User.IsInRole("ActiveDirectory"))
    {
        //Do something
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("./NoAccess.html", true);
    }
}
```

But all the time it is not comes to else condition, but user is valid. Please let me knw anything else I need to do? Or please send me the code whcih can found all user in an AD group.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please format your code so that someone else except you can read it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the help here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890.aspx

(updated link)

Comment: @Shameer use this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice the VS version. A version independent link would also work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890.aspx